# How to enlarge/resize topojson map file with Vincent

Tags: topojson, vega, vincent

I am trying to use Vincent to create state zip code maps. I'm using the State files posted on [github](https://github.com/storiesofsolidarity/us-data/blob/gh-pages/geography/zcta/Maryland.topo.json) by @jlev. However, when I try to display them in iPython notebook or even when I render the same vega object on an HTML page, the map shows up very small with a lot of white space around it. I am using the equirectangular projection. When I try to increase the scale in iPython notebook, the map gets only slightly larger, but the whitespace surrounding the map gets exponentially larger. I can import them into mapshaper.org and they look fine, so I don't think there are any issues with the topo.json files. Looking for some guidance on resizing these in Vincent. The most luck I've had with this is by changing the scale on the topo.json file itself, but I can only increase these so much before the map gets distorted with a lot of extra lines.

Here is my python code:

```
zip_topo = r'topo_files/Maryland.topo.json'
geo_data = [{'name': 'Maryland',
         'url': zip_topo,
         'feature': 'Maryland.geo'}]

vis =         vincent.Map(geo_data=geo_data,scale=8000,projection='equirectangular')
vis.display()
```